# How to Modify sku Magento 2 in bulk?

Tags: magento2

Someone can help in modifying in bulk certain sku without script? I have searched information online but didn't find. I can use Magmi as well. Thank you.

Comment: please explain me more...

Comment: Without a script? So direct SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

First, create BulkUpdateSku.php file on the Magento2 root folder and add the below code.

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$fileCsv        = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
$moduleReader   = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader');
$directoryList  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$file           = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File');

$filePath = "skus.csv"; 
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    $rows = $fileCsv->getData($filePath);
    $count = 0;
    $successSku = [];
    $failedSku = [];
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if($count > 0) {
            $oldSku  = (isset($row[0])) ? $row[0] : "";
            $newSku  = (isset($row[1])) ? $row[1] : "";
            if($oldSku && $newSku) {
                $productId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($oldSku);
                if($productId) {
                    try {
                        $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
                        $product = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
                        $product->setSku($newSku);
                        $product->save();
                        $successSku[$newSku] = $newSku;
                    }
                    catch (\Exception $e) {
                        echo "Cannot retrieve products from Magento: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>"; 
                    }
                }else {
                    $failedSku[$oldSku] = $oldSku;  
                }
            }
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
```

CSV format:

[image]

After putting the **skus.csv** file on the Magento2 root folder with your **new SKU** & **old SKU** data.

After running ***BulkUpdateSku.php*** file in your browser for example. http://xyz-magento2.com/BulkUpdateSku.php and check your products in the admin end.

**Note:** 
If you like the answer please give thumbs up.

Comment: Original question did say without script. Also I'd probably include a note that this type solution should only be temporary.  Using root scripts which would be publically accessible and object manager is a bad idea. If it's something you are going to use frequently create a console script and inject classes as per magento docs.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code looks quite simple, will try it anyway.

Comment: @Daniel You are welcome,  If you like the answer please give thumbs up.

Comment: @DominicXigen Yes you are absolutely right but its a one time script once a task is completed we can remove the script from the root, the better way this can be done creating a module also for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the script, use the simple queries to achieve the updates

Create one temp table say, update_skus with two columns "old_sku, new_sku"

```
CREATE TABLE update_skus (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    old_sku VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    new_sku VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Import the csv file into the temp table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_path' 
INTO TABLE update_skus 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Use the below query to update all product names to the new name in the temp table

```
update catalog_product_entity ce join update_skus us on us.sku = ce.old_sku set ce.sku = us.new_name;
```

Delete the temp table, once you verified the new skus for the product

```
delete table update_sks;
```